# All data is in enter() placeholder (D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've got an update function with this code:

```
// actualy fetched from server. array of JS objects that I parsed to right type
var xData = [{
    id: 234234 // parsed as integer
    date: 15/11/2001 // parsed as date
    price: 6512 // parsed as integer
}];

// triggred by the user
function updateSVG() {

 // fetch new data from ther server
 xData = [];
 xData = [{
    id: 234234 // parsed as integer
    data: 15/11/2001 // parsed as date
    price: 6512 // parsed as integer
}];

 // join data
 var x = svg.selectAll(".x-class")
     .data(xData, function(d) { return d.id; });

 // new data
 x.enter().append("image")
     .attr('class', 'x-class')
     .attr("xlink:href", "x-image.png")
     .attr("width", 16)
     .attr("height", 19)
     .attr('y', 0);

 // current and new data
 x.transition()
     .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.date); });

 /// old data
 x.exit().remove();

}
```

What I expect is when I run this function the second or third time, most of the data will be UPDATE (i.e. not in enter), and just a few of the data will be in enter() and exit().

But all my data is in enter(). No matter what. The d.id is unique for sure. Everything works well as expected but this issue. When I inspect the x object before and after I fetche the new data, all my data is in the enter() placeholder.

Any ideas? What am I missing?

Comment: What is `xData`?  And where is the code where you make the initial data join?

Comment: I added some example code.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're doing. Could you add a complete example please?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Can you elaborate on "all my data is in enter()"

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. When this function is running, D3 doesn't remember my old data, and puts all my new data items in the enter() collection, even though there's a lot of data that already had .x-class element (and they have the same d.id key from earlier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code problems (Let us know if any of these help):

1. What is `x` in the case of `x(d.date)`? Do you mean `xData` here?

   `x.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.date); })`
2. What is this doing? You haven't defined `data`, or `y`. (or `arrayObjectIndexOf` and `yOffset` but I suspect those are as implied)

   `return y(data[arrayObjectIndexOf(data, d.date, 'date')].price) - yOffset;`

Also, since D3 is a data manipulation library, it's usually more difficult to help when we don't know what your data looks like. Sometimes we get an idea (`d.date`) but it could be important here (since you're apparently finding a price elsewhere instead of doing `d.price`)

Comment: What do you expect x(d.date) and y(d.date) to do? Are they scales? Change them to be xScale(d.date) and yScale(d.date) because your "x" is already used as a variable for the d3 selector.

Comment: Also, try selecting ("image.x-class") instead. Might not make a difference. And what is your "svg" variable. This might make a difference. How about trying your code in a jsfiddle so we can see everything that's going on.